# Чем может быть вызвана такая разница во времени выполнения этих двух программ?

Tags: алгоритм

Здесь есть два практически одинаковые функции обеспечивающих сортировки по алгоритму выбора. Однако первый пример, работает на 1 секунду стабильно быстрее. Прошу подсказать, чем это может быть обусловлено? Данные в обоих случаях использовались одни и те же:

1)

```
 def sort_from_book(data):
        new_arr = []
        for i in range(len(data)):
            smallest = findSmallest(data)
            new_arr.append(data.pop(smallest))
        return new_arr


def findSmallest(data):
    smallest = data[0]
    smallest_index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        if data[i] < smallest:
            smallest = data[i]
            smallest_index = i
    return smallest_index
```

2)

```
  def sort(data):
        new_data = []
        for _ in range(len(data)):
            max = 0
            for j in range(1, len(data)):
                if data[j] < data[max]:
                    max = j
            new_data.append(data.pop(max))
        return new_data
```

Comment: Вы пробовали использовать стандартные методы сортировки?

Comment: Код ещё не запускал, но например во втором примере отсутствует эквивалент переменной `smallest` из первого примера, из-за чего лишнее обращение по индексу может замедлять работу

Comment: Я думал сложность обращения по индексу и так стабильно О(1) и разници нет

Comment: Ок, я попробую и отпишу

Comment: Да, реально, проблема в той переменной

Comment: Ойой, все ясно, я позабил, что используються тут списки а не массиви